# How to prove this inequality in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have $(X, d)$, a metric space, and I have to prove that
$$|d(x,u)-d(y,u)|\le d(x,y)+d(u,v).$$ I can see that what I have to prove are two inequalities $-d(x,y)-d(u,v)\le d(x,u)-d(y,u)$ and $d(x,u)-d(y,u)\le d(x,y)+d(u,v)$. For the second one I used this inequality (that I already proved) $|d(x,u)-d(y,u)|\le d(x,y)$ and I get $d(x,u)-d(y,u)\le d(x,y)\le d(x,y)+d(u,v)$, I hope it's ok. However with the first one, I got a little frustrated.

Comment: I think somebody made a typo and you should show $\lvert d(x,u) - d(y,v)\rvert \leqslant d(x,y) + d(u,v)$.

Comment: Drawing a picture might be helpful for you.

Comment: @DanielFischer yep, i asked and it turns out it does has a typo ¬¬

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the triangle inequality $d(x,u)\le d(x,y)+d(y,u)\le d(x,y)+d(u,v)+d(y,v).$ Similarly, $d(y,v)\le d(x,y)+d(x,v)\le d(x,y)+d(u,v)+d(x,u)$, so $d(x,u)-d(y,v)\le d(x,y)+d(u,v)$ and $d(y,v)-d(x,u)\le d(x,y)+d(u,v).$ Combine the last two to get $|d(x,u)-d(y,v)|\le d(x,y)+d(u,v).$

Answer (score 2):

I thought a little picture might help the intuition (as suggested by @Jack)

- Case 1 : $ d(x,u)-d(y,v) \le d(x,y)+d(u,v)$

  $\Leftrightarrow \color{\red}{d(x,u)} \le \color{\green}{d(x,y) +d(y,v) + d(v,u)}$ (by symmetry of $d(\cdot)$). This holds by a twofold application of the triangle inequality which can be visualized in the following picture.

[image]

- Case 2 : $ d(y,v) - d(x,u) \le d(x,y)+d(u,v)$

  $\Leftrightarrow \color{\red}{d(y,v)} \le \color{\green}{d(y,x) + d(x,u) + d(u,v)}$ (by symmetry of $d(\cdot)$). Again a similar picture can be drawn to illustrate the double application of the triangle inequality.